# Web API 2 method developed using ADO.NET is not performing well, takes 53 seconds

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I am creating API for Android app using Asp.Net Web API2. There is a method which fetches members data from the table. I am sorting and listing members based on arrangements(int) and name(string). The first sort by arrangements which value is not 0. then sort by name which value is 0. Everything working perfect but query execution taking 53234 ms as shown in postman.PErformance goes worst when I use EF6. I tested it using live URL and not on localhost. I have cloud server. Please check and help me in performance improvement. There are around 1000 rows/records only. There is an another query/stored procedure also which list nearby members based on latitude and longitude and execution time is hardly 2 seconds. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks

## API Method

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetAllMembersOfClub")]
    public APIResult GetAllMembersOfClub()
    {
        APIResult apiResult = new APIResult();

        List<MemberData> lstMember = new List<MemberData>();

        var cmd = new SqlCommand("Rotary1.usp_GetMembersWithArrangements", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clubId", DbType.Int32).Value = clubID;       
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var objMember = new MemberData();


            objMember.CountryCode = dr["CountryCode"].ToString();
            objMember.ClubName = dr["ClubName"].ToString();

            objMember.Name = dr["name"].ToString();
            objMember.Classification = dr["Classification"].ToString();
            objMember.OfficeAdrs1 = dr["OfficeAdrs1"].ToString();
            objMember.OfficeAdrs2 = dr["OfficeAdrs2"].ToString();
            objMember.OfficeAdrs3 = dr["OfficeAdrs3"].ToString();
            objMember.ResAdrs1 = dr["ResAdrs1"].ToString();
            objMember.ResAdrs2 = dr["ResAdrs2"].ToString();
            objMember.ResAdrs3 = dr["ResAdrs3"].ToString();
            objMember.Spouse = dr["Wife"].ToString();
            objMember.Phone = dr["Phone"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["Mobile"].ToString();
            objMember.EmailId = dr["EmailId"].ToString();

            objMember.Since = dr["Since"].ToString();
            objMember.Title1 = dr["title1"].ToString();
            objMember.Title2 = dr["title2"].ToString();
            objMember.Title3 = dr["title3"].ToString();
            objMember.Title4 = dr["title4"].ToString();
            objMember.PostHeld = dr["PostHeld"].ToString();
            objMember.Imgg = dr["imgg"].ToString();


            objMember.Anniversary = dr["Aniversary"].ToString();
            objMember.Position = dr["Position"].ToString();
            objMember.Ophone = dr["ophone"].ToString();
            objMember.Children = dr["Children"].ToString();

            objMember.Spouse = dr["Wife"].ToString();
            objMember.Latitude = dr["Latitude"].ToString();
            objMember.Longitude = dr["Longitude"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile10 = dr["mobile10"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile2 = dr["mobile2"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile3 = dr["mobile3"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile4 = dr["mobile4"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile5 = dr["mobile5"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile6 = dr["mobile6"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile7 = dr["mobile7"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile8 = dr["mobile8"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile9 = dr["mobile9"].ToString();
            objMember.Noti = dr["noti"].ToString();
            objMember.Arrange = dr["arrange"].ToString();
            try
            {
                objMember.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DOB"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyy");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                objMember.DOB = "";
            }



            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile2) || objMember.Mobile2 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile2 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile2"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile3) || objMember.Mobile3 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile3 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile3"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile4) || objMember.Mobile4 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile4 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile4"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile5) || objMember.Mobile5 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile5 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile5"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile6) || objMember.Mobile6 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile6 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile6"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile7) || objMember.Mobile7 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile7 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile7"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile8) || objMember.Mobile8 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile8 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile8"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile9) || objMember.Mobile9 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile9 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile9"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile10) || objMember.Mobile10 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile10 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile10"].ToString();
            }
            lstMember.Add(objMember);
        }
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();

         cmd = new SqlCommand("Rotary1.usp_GetMembersWithArrangements1", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clubId", DbType.Int32).Value = clubID;
        conn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var objMember = new MemberData();


            objMember.CountryCode = dr["CountryCode"].ToString();
            objMember.ClubName = dr["ClubName"].ToString();

            objMember.Name = dr["name"].ToString();
            objMember.Classification = dr["Classification"].ToString();
            objMember.OfficeAdrs1 = dr["OfficeAdrs1"].ToString();
            objMember.OfficeAdrs2 = dr["OfficeAdrs2"].ToString();
            objMember.OfficeAdrs3 = dr["OfficeAdrs3"].ToString();
            objMember.ResAdrs1 = dr["ResAdrs1"].ToString();
            objMember.ResAdrs2 = dr["ResAdrs2"].ToString();
            objMember.ResAdrs3 = dr["ResAdrs3"].ToString();
            objMember.Spouse = dr["Wife"].ToString();
            objMember.Phone = dr["Phone"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["Mobile"].ToString();
            objMember.EmailId = dr["EmailId"].ToString();

            objMember.Since = dr["Since"].ToString();
            objMember.Title1 = dr["title1"].ToString();
            objMember.Title2 = dr["title2"].ToString();
            objMember.Title3 = dr["title3"].ToString();
            objMember.Title4 = dr["title4"].ToString();
            objMember.PostHeld = dr["PostHeld"].ToString();
            objMember.Imgg = dr["imgg"].ToString();


            objMember.Anniversary = dr["Aniversary"].ToString();
            objMember.Position = dr["Position"].ToString();
            objMember.Ophone = dr["ophone"].ToString();
            objMember.Children = dr["Children"].ToString();

            objMember.Spouse = dr["Wife"].ToString();
            objMember.Latitude = dr["Latitude"].ToString();
            objMember.Longitude = dr["Longitude"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile10 = dr["mobile10"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile2 = dr["mobile2"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile3 = dr["mobile3"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile4 = dr["mobile4"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile5 = dr["mobile5"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile6 = dr["mobile6"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile7 = dr["mobile7"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile8 = dr["mobile8"].ToString();
            objMember.Mobile9 = dr["mobile9"].ToString();
            objMember.Noti = dr["noti"].ToString();
            objMember.Arrange = dr["arrange"].ToString();
            try
            {
                objMember.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DOB"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyy");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                objMember.DOB = "";
            }



            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile2) || objMember.Mobile2 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile2 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile2"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile3) || objMember.Mobile3 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile3 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile3"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile4) || objMember.Mobile4 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile4 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile4"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile5) || objMember.Mobile5 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile5 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile5"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile6) || objMember.Mobile6 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile6 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile6"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile7) || objMember.Mobile7 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile7 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile7"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile8) || objMember.Mobile8 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile8 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile8"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile9) || objMember.Mobile9 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile9 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile9"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objMember.Mobile10) || objMember.Mobile10 != "")
            {
                objMember.Mobile10 = "+" + dr["CountryCode"].ToString() + dr["mobile10"].ToString();
            }


            lstMember.Add(objMember);
        }

        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();

        apiResult.ReturnData = lstMember;
        apiResult.ReturnCode = "1";
        apiResult.ReturnMessage = "success";

        return apiResult;
    }
```

## Queries/Stored Procedures

```
USE [myDb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE Procedure [Rotary1].[usp_GetMembersWithArrangements]    
@clubId INT    
As    
BEGIN     
BEGIN       
 select * from main where arrange<>0 and club=@clubId order by arrange desc  
END           
END
GO
```

## Second Procedure

```
USE [myDb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE Procedure [Rotary1].[usp_GetMembersWithArrangements1]    
@clubId INT    
As    
BEGIN     
BEGIN       
select * from main where arrange=0 and club=@clubId order by name   
END           
END
GO
```

## Below is table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[main](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [title1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [title2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [title3] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [title4] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Classification] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [position] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [PostHeld] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [OfficeAdrs1] [text] NULL,
    [OfficeAdrs2] [text] NULL,
    [OfficeAdrs3] [text] NULL,
    [ophone] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Mobile] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [EmailId] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [ResAdrs1] [text] NULL,
    [ResAdrs2] [text] NULL,
    [ResAdrs3] [text] NULL,
    [Wife] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [children] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NULL,
    [Since] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [imgg] [text] NULL,
    [Aniversary] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [arrange] [int] NULL,
    [club] [int] NULL,
    [noti] [int] NULL,
    [ClubName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Latitude] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Longitude] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [mobile2] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile3] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile4] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile5] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile6] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile7] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile8] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile9] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile10] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CountryCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Status] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_main_Status]  DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_main] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public List<Member> GetMembers(string name="")
    {
        var param1 = new SqlParameter("@Name",name );
        var result = _Context.Database.SqlQuery<Member>("exec GetMembersList @Name", param1).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Call stored procedure using Database.SqlQuery method of entity framework without using SqlDataReader and while loop